Bash variable losing value
I recently added a variable to a script process that will be used as a replacement value via sed for an output script (not bash). This is one of many variables set within an if statement and (for reasons I cannot seem to deduce) the variable loses its value once outside of the if statement. This is not occurring with any of the other variables that are set within the if statement. Code and expanded results follow.
if [ ${ModeTyp} == "P" ] ; then
    PC_DB=idpacleanelig
    PS2_DB=idpaprodserv2
    PV_DB=idpaprodviews
    PV_OUT=idpaprodviews
    P_DB=idpaprod
    P_DBIN=idpaprod
    CERNH="CE_RunHierarchyControl_T"                  |
    CECONTROL=CE_LegacyControlTable_RHMv5
  echo "CERNH value is ${CERNH} after Default Population in if prod statement"
else
    PC_DB=hfsdevsandbox
    PS2_DB=hfsdevsandbox
    PV_DB=idpaprodviews
    PV_OUT=hfsdevsandbox
    P_DB=hfsdevsandbox
    P_DBIN=idpaprod
    CERNH="CE_RunHierarchyControl_T"                  |
    CECONTROL=CE_LegacyControlTable_RHMv5
    GOTOLBL_1=""
    GOTOLBL_3=""
  echo "CERNH value is ${CERNH} after Default Population in if test statement"
fi

echo "CERNH value is ${CERNH} after Default Population"

RUN RESULTS:
+ '[' T == P ']'
+ PC_DB=hfsdevsandbox
+ PS2_DB=hfsdevsandbox
+ PV_DB=idpaprodviews
+ PV_OUT=hfsdevsandbox
+ P_DB=hfsdevsandbox
+ P_DBIN=idpaprod
+ CECONTROL=CE_LegacyControlTable_RHMv5
+ CERNH=CE_RunHierarchyControl_T
+ GOTOLBL_1=
+ GOTOLBL_3=
+ echo 'CERNH value is CE_RunHierarchyControl_T after Default Population in if test statement'
CERNH value is CE_RunHierarchyControl_T after Default Population in if test statement
+ echo 'CERNH value is  after Default Population'
CERNH value is  after Default Population


This is practically the same as Why is my variable local in one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop? Note the pipe sign to the right on the CERNH="..." line. Your assignments involved in that pipe run in subshells (i.e. CERNH and CECONTROL, and changes within a subshell aren't visible in the main shell script.
